# Why am I getting nulls for my output?

Tags: java

So I tried researching online and I have a feeling it is my toString(), but it is sort of right in the way that I can't think of any other way it would be.

I want to be able to output: Lexie- Height: 2.6ft. Born: 11/5/2009

My code looks like:

```
import java.util.*; 
class Kid {  
    String name; 
    double height; 
    GregorianCalendar bDay; 
    public Kid () { 
        this.name = "HEAD";
        this.height = 1; 
        this.bDay = new GregorianCalendar(1111,1,1); 
    } 

    public Kid (String n, double h, String date) { 
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/", true);
        n = this.name;
        h = this.height;
    } 
    /**
    public String toString() { 
        return (this.name + ", Height: " + this.height + "ft., Born: "
        + this.month + "/" + this.day + "/" + this.year);
    } 
    */
    public String toString() {
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        return (this.name + ", Height: " + this.height + "ft., Born: "
        + this.bDay);
    }
} //end class
```

Calling the Kid class is below

```
class Driver { 
    public static void main (String[] args) { 
        Kid kid1 = new Kid("Lexie", 2.6, "11/5/2009");
        System.out.println(kid1.toString());
    } //end main method 
} //end class
```

Comment: You tokenize the input but you do not construct birthday object from given date

Comment: There are several problems with your code. Another one of them: you probably mean `this.name = n;` instead of `n = this.name;`.

Comment: Why would you do this.name = n?

Comment: Assignment is from right to left.  If you want the value 1 in x, you say x = 1.

Comment: @user1283885 So you'd set the property from the parameter, instead of the parameter from the property.

Comment: It's an assignment - the variable/field on the left has its value set to the value on the right. Here, you're providing `n` and you want `this.name` to be set to that value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expressions in your constructor are the wrong way round - you have `n = this.name` where you should have `this.name = n`. Similarly for `this.height`. Also, you aren't currently setting the `bDay` field at all. Thus all fields are indeed `null`.

Comment: Same problem with `h = this.height` instead of `this.height = h`.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Didn't think it necessary to spell that out explicitly...

Comment: It was more for the poster to see so they don't make one change and it's still not working correctly.

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I posted the answer before I'd read some of the comments under the question. Better to be sure, I suspect...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public Kid (String n, double h, String date) { 
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(date, "/");
        this.name = n;
        this.height = h;
        this.bDay = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    }
```

Comment: Only problem with that is the fact that Gregorian Calender wants Strings as arguments, not ints......

Comment: st.nextToken() returns a String not an int.

Comment: My bad, other way around.
Edit: wants three arguments (all integers) 
so copying from a book:
GregorianCalendar(year:int, month: int, dayOfMonth: int)

Comment: Edited the response, added the conversion to int, Integer.parseInt().

Comment: Hate to bother you again,
but StringTokenizer is converting everything to int, therefore, the / gets converted and error is thrown.
This is my assumption on why it does it^.
May not be the right  reason.

Comment: edited again, removed the third parameter of StringTokenizer which was telling the tokenizer to return the delimiters as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your constructor and the type of the bDay:

```
private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd/MM/yyyy";
String name; 
double height; 
Date bDay; 

public Kid () { 
    this.name = "HEAD";
    this.height = 1; 
    this.bDay = new Date(); 
} 

public Kid (String n, double h, String date) { 
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    this.bDay = df.parse(date);
    this.name = n;
    this.height = h;
} 

public String toString() {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    return (this.name + ", Height: " + this.height + "ft., Born: "
    + df.format(this.bDay));
}
```